# How to test a string returned in a method Java

Tags: java, methods

Ok so I am trying to figure how to test a string that is returned from a method in Java. I know I cannot test a string but am confused on how to change the return to be able to test it as a char or something different.

This is where the issue is that I can't seem to get past.

```
if(flip().equals("Heads")) {
            headsCount++;
            }
```

full code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many times should I flip the coin? ");
        int headsCount = 0;
        int flips = input.nextInt();
        for(flips = flips; flips >= 1; flips--) {
            flip();
            }

        if(flip().equals("Heads")) {
            headsCount++;
            }

        System.out.println(headsCount);

    }

    public static int flip() {`enter code here`
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        if (rand == 1) {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            }
        if (rand != 1){
            System.out.println("tails");
            }
        return rand;
    }
```

Comment: why does the flip method have to return an int?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `flip` method to this:

```
    public static String flip() {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        String result = null;
        if (rand == 1) {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            result = "Heads";
        }
        if (rand != 1){
            System.out.println("tails");
            result = "tails";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And, change the `for` loop to following:

```
for(flips = flips; flips >= 1; flips--) {
    String result = flip();
    if("Heads".equals(result)) {
            headsCount++;
      }
}
```

Comment: your if could simply be `if("heads".equals(result))`

Comment: "Heads", taking care of case sensitivity. It might be instructive for the OP to have a look at [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: This worked. Return the string and then assign the returned string to result. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many times should I flip the coin? ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int headsCount = 0;
    int flips = input.nextInt();
    for(int flips = flips; flips >= 1; flips--) {
        flip();
        }

    if(flip() == true) {
        headsCount++;
        }

    System.out.println(headsCount);

}

public static boolean flip() {
    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    if (rand == 1) {
        System.out.println("Heads");
        return true;
        }
    if (rand != 1){
        System.out.println("tails");
        return false;
        }
}
```

So your don´t even need to compare Strings

Answer (score 0):

1. You're testing for a String when it's an int returned

Should be something like:

```
//variable ensures that we are not testing a separate flip all the time
int result = flip();
if (result == 1) {
    headscount++;
} else {
    tailscount++;
}
```

2. Your methodology for retrieving a random is botched... to a huge probability of it being tails

   ```
   Random random = new Random();
   //from + random.nextInt(to - from + 1)
   //0 + random.nextInt(1-0+1)
   int result = random.nextInt(2);
   ```
3. Your for loop is running a process and then outside your for loop you are testing whether or not a single flip is heads which is completely independent with regards to probability of heads/tails outcome and the rest of your flips.

   ```
   for(int x = 0; x < flips; x++) {
   //variable ensures that we are not testing a separate flip all the time
      int result = flip();
      if (result == 1) {
             headscount++;
      } else {
             tailscount++;
      }
   }
   ```